# How do I evaluate the following mathematical statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Determine whether this statement is $T$ or $F$, or whether its truth value cannot be determined without knowledge of the value of $x$. If the truth value cannot be determined, show one example of a value of $x$ for which the claim is true, and one example for which the claim is false. $x$ represents a specific integer.

$$x^2 \neq 36 \quad or \quad x\ge6$$

It seems that this statement cannot be determined. I don't think that the logical disjunction allows for me to evaluate the truth value of the statement. However, I guess that I can still give a value of $x$ for which the claim is $T$ and one for when its $F$. Is my reasoning correct? I feel like this question is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value 
of the expression when
$x=5$, then $x=6$.

Comment: It will be $T$ for both, no? $5^2 \neq 36$ is $T$, but $x=5$ is $F$. However, $T$ or $F$ is still $T$

$x=6$ will produce $F$ or $T$ which evaluates to $T$

Answer (score 0):

Try $x= -6$, if your definition of integer allows negative values. Otherwise try $x=6$, then $x>6$ and $0\le x < 6$ and check wether your statement is true.